# Remove comma if value after comma is empty in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let Suppose we have two variables in sql

```
DECLARE @str1 nvarchar(max) = 'FirstName,MiddleName,LastName'
DECLARE @str2 nvarchar(max) = 'John,,Adams'
```

Now you can see that value after first comma is empty in second variable if this case occur i want to remove the same entry from string .

```
-- Expected Result Would be 
Result of str1 =  FirstName,LastName
Result of str2 =  'John,Adams'
```

**NOTE**
It is sure that if str1 have 3 items then str2 will also have 3 , regardlass of empty string

**Update**

Above given is just an example `str1` could have 100 comma str2 will always have same number of comma as str1 does . Now what we want to do is that suppose we got an empty entry at any postion of str2 (suppose 10 or 20 or 32 .... anywhere ) item with same positon from str1 will be removed.

Please tell me if anyone still have confusion

Comment: Could there be a `@str2 = 'John, James,'` value or `@str2 = ',James,Adams'`?

Comment: NO @HansKesting It will never have any trailing or leading comma

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve and why are you trying to do this in SQL? String manipulation should be done on the client's side or during ETL. Or the actual problem could be solved by converting the CSV values to table variables and joining them

Comment: @Ancient I've added a dynamic answer

Comment: better to normalize your data so you don't have to do string manipulation in TSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Replace`. Try this.

```
DECLARE @str1 NVARCHAR(max) = 'FirstName,MiddleName,LastName'
DECLARE @str2 NVARCHAR(max) = 'John,,Adams'

SELECT Parsename(Replace(Replace(@str2, ',,', ',abc,'), ',', '.'), 3)
       + ','
       + Parsename(Replace(Replace(@str2, ',,', ',abc,'), ',', '.'), 1)

SELECT Parsename(Replace(Replace(@str1, ',,', ',abc,'), ',', '.'), 3)
       + ','
       + Parsename(Replace(Replace(@str1, ',,', ',abc,'), ',', '.'), 1)
```

**Update :** for more than four items

```
DECLARE @str1 NVARCHAR(max) = 'FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Address'
DECLARE @str2 NVARCHAR(max) = 'Jhon,,,Berlin'

SELECT LEFT(@str1, Charindex(',', @str1)-1) + ','
       + Reverse(LEFT(Reverse(@str1), Charindex(',', Reverse(@str1))-1))

SELECT LEFT(@str2, Charindex(',', @str2)-1) + ','
       + Reverse(LEFT(Reverse(@str2), Charindex(',', Reverse(@str2))-1))
```

Comment: This won't work for this example **DECLARE str1 nvarchar(max) = 'FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,c'
DECLARE str2 nvarchar(max) = 'John,,Adams,d'** @Ancient

Comment: @SarathAvanavu is right it will not work , and i already said your first was also a working solution but it will not cover all scenarios and still current answer will also not .

Comment: I marked it answered because it works for a static condition not any . that's why and let me guess that both of you can see

Comment: I marked you answer correct but i will give you bounty if you improve your answer for dynamic

Comment: If its so, thats Ok. Why I mentioned is that the next one who will be finding for this question will be easy to tackle it. I know NoDisplayName is good in queries. So I suggest him to plz update with that too :) @Ancient

Comment: @Ancient - what is the expected output in that case.

Comment: My friend. Plz update that too. The scenario I had mentioned can also happen for someone. @NoDisplayName

Comment: str1 will reflect str2 , like if str2 have an empty item at comma position 10 then your query should remove the 10th item from str1 . Got it ?

Comment: @SarathAvanavu - no am not clear just tell me what is the expected output in your case.

Comment: I have mentioned in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e437/2 . Since fiddle is not showing the actual result, just run it on SQL Server @NoDisplayName

Comment: @SarathAvanavu no, this is said by OP.**Suppose i have str1 = 'FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Address' and str2 = 'Jhon,,,Berlin' . In This case MiddleName and LastName should be removed from str1** what you are saying totally contradicting

Comment: Take this str1='FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Address' and str='Jhon,,Berlin,d'. So it should return 'FirstName,LastName,Address' for str1 and 'Jhon,Berlin,d' for str2 .Right? @NoDisplayName

Comment: Its OK in 7th comment. But he have mentioned that should be affected in str2 also in the question @NoDisplayName

Comment: If this is your solution you need a different problem.

Comment: @SarathAvanavu see my answer which is dynamic (using numbers table)

Answer (score 0):

OK this works regardless the number of commas or the number of missing values. It uses a number or tally table which I've included for simplicity of this example:

```
;WITH Tally (Number) AS
(
    -- 1000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
)
SELECT *
Into #Numbers
FROM Tally;

DECLARE @str1 NVARCHAR(max) = 'FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Initial,County,State,Address'
DECLARE @str2 NVARCHAR(max) = 'Jhon,,Isiah,,Black Forest,,Berlin'

DECLARE @result1 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @result2 VARCHAR(MAX)


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@str1, Number, 
            CHARINDEX(',', @str1 + ',', Number) - Number),
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number) AS RN
            FROM #Numbers
            WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@str1))
                AND SUBSTRING(',' + @str1, Number, 1) = ','
),
CTE2
As
(
    SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@str2, Number, 
            CHARINDEX(',', @str2 + ',', Number) - Number),
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number) AS RN
            FROM #Numbers
            WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@str2))
                AND SUBSTRING(',' + @str2, Number, 1) = ','
)
SELECT @result1 = COALESCE(@result1+', ' ,'') + CTE.Item, @result2 = COALESCE(@result2+', ' ,'') + CTE2.Item
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN CTE2
    ON CTE.RN = CTE2.RN
WHERE CTE2.Item <> ''

SELECT @result1
SELECT @result2
```

This gives the following results:

```
FirstName, LastName, County, Address
Jhon, Isiah, Black Forest, Berlin
```

Of course you would want to create a permanent numbers table.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @commapos1 int 
DECLARE @commapos2 int

SET @commapos1 =CHARINDEX(",",@str1, 1)          --position of first comma
SET @commapos2 =CHARINDEX(",",@str1, commapos1)  --position of second comma

SELECT LEFT(@str1, commapos1), RIGHT (@str1, commapos2+1)
```